# I want to change this code from class component to functional component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on integrating 2 different js files one is in functional component and the other one is in class component. I want the class component file to be converted to functional component. I am new to reactjs and class component. If this can be converted to functional component that would be useful.

```js
import  React from "react";
import {Tabs , Button} from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const { TabPane } = Tabs;



class Tabbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      focusingPaneKey: '',
      openingPaneKeys: [],
    }
  }

  openPane = (paneKey) => {
    this.setState(({ ...state }) => {
      if (!state.openingPaneKeys.includes(paneKey)) {
        state.openingPaneKeys = [...state.openingPaneKeys, paneKey]
      }

      state.focusingPaneKey = paneKey
      return state
    })
  }

  closePane = (paneKey) => { 
    this.setState(({ ...state }) => {
      if (paneKey === state.focusingPaneKey) {
        const paneKeyIndex = state.openingPaneKeys.indexOf(paneKey)
        state.focusingPaneKey = state.openingPaneKeys[paneKeyIndex - 1]
      }

      state.openingPaneKeys = state.openingPaneKeys.filter((openingPaneKey) => openingPaneKey !== paneKey)

      return state
    })
  }

  handleTabsEdit = (key, action) => {
    if (action === 'remove') {
      this.closePane(key)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { panes } = this.props
    const keysOfPane = Object.keys(panes)

    return (
      <div className="tab-section">
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          {keysOfPane.map((key) => (
            <Button key={key} onClick={() => this.openPane(key)}>
              ADD Tab-{key}
            </Button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <Tabs
          hideAdd
          onChange={this.openPane}
          activeKey={this.state.focusingPaneKey}
          type="editable-card"
          onEdit={this.handleTabsEdit}
        >
          {this.state.openingPaneKeys
            .map((key) => panes[key])
            .map((pane) => (
              <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
                {pane.content}
              </TabPane>
            ))}
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const panes = {
  1: { key: '1', title: 'Tab 1', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 1' },
  2: { key: '2', title: 'Tab 2', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 2' },
  3: { key: '3', title: 'Tab 3', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 3' },
}

export default Tabbar;
```

Comment: You could see this as an opportunity to learn about React, class components, and function components. You can do it!

Comment: https://nimblewebdeveloper.com/blog/convert-react-class-to-function-component maybe help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { Tabs, Button } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const Tabbar = (props) => {

  const [focusingPaneKey, setFocusingPaneKey] = useState('')
  cons[openingPaneKeys, setOpeningPaneKeys] = useState([])

  const openPane = (paneKey) => {
    setOpeningPaneKeys(oldState => {
      if (!oldState.includes(paneKey)) {
        return [...oldState, paneKey]
      }
      return oldState
    })

    setFocusingPaneKey(paneKey)
  }

  const closePane = (paneKey) => {
    if (paneKey === focusingPaneKey) {
      const paneKeyIndex = openingPaneKeys.indexOf(paneKey)
      setFocusingPaneKey(openingPaneKeys[paneKeyIndex - 1])
    }

    setOpeningPaneKeys(openingPaneKeys.filter((openingPaneKey) => openingPaneKey !== paneKey))
  }

  const handleTabsEdit = useCallback((key, action) => {
    if (action === 'remove') {
      closePane(key)
    }
  }, [closePane])

  const { panes } = props
  const keysOfPane = Object.keys(panes)

  return (
    <div className="tab-section">
      <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
        {keysOfPane.map((key) => (
          <Button key={key} onClick={() => openPane(key)}>
            ADD Tab-{key}
          </Button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <Tabs
        hideAdd
        onChange={openPane}
        activeKey={focusingPaneKey}
        type="editable-card"
        onEdit={handleTabsEdit}
      >
        {openingPaneKeys
          .map((key) => panes[key])
          .map((pane) => (
            <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
              {pane.content}
            </TabPane>
          ))}
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tabbar
```